# Prove that any group of 14 people must contain either 5 mutual friends or 3 mutual strangers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

So I think I have the answer to this problem, but there's something about it that's bothering me:

Suppose we choose a fixed point with $13$ edges coming out of it.

There must be at least

$a)$ $9$ red edges (friends)

OR

$b)$ $5$ blue edges (strangers)

because $8 + 4 < 13$.

In case $b)$, among the $5$ edges if any are blue then we have blue triangle with our fixed point, and so we are done. Otherwise, they are all red and we have a red-pentagon, also as desired.

In case $a)$, among $9$ people there are $3$ mutual strangers or $4$ mutual friends. If the former, we are done. If the latter, since the $4$ friends are red edges to our fixed point then we have $5$ mutual friends including our fixed point, again as desired.

---

Namely, for case $a)$, do I need to include the case if among $9$ people there are $4$ mutual STRANGERS or $3$ mutual FRIENDS? If so, how? If not, well why not?

This has been bothering me for quite some time and I would appreciate an answer!

Thanks!

Comment: yes that's correct! Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution to the problem is good. Ofcourse this relies on the fact that among 9 people there **allways** are 3 mutual strangers or 4 mutual friends. This is a known bound so you can use it, but if this is some kind of hand in exercise then you may have to do that step too.

Thus either you use the known proposition or you prove it. In both cases you do not have to consider 4 mutual strangers and 3 mutual friends, since you still know that there are 3 mutual strangers and 4 mutual friends.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. But I'm still a bit confused, do you mind clarifying a bit? We proved R(3,4) = 9 in class, so I'm not worried about doing that step. My question is, I know that R(3,4) = R(4,3) = 9, so isn't it entirely possible that among the 9 people, that 4 are mutual strangers and 3 are mutual friends instead of the reverse case? Why do I not need to consider this?

Comment: Hmmmmm! Is it because "strangers" and "friends" are arbitrary labels and that what really matters is that there are these two distinct groups with specific numbers?

Comment: R(3,4)= 9 means that among 9 people there ALLWAYS are 3 mutual strangers or 4 mutual friends. Hence we may use this fact. That R(3,4)=R(4,3) means that we also may find a group of 3 mutual friends or 4 mutual strangers in all graphs, however this we do not need to use here.